# Не работает метод распознавания лиц OpenCV Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Проблема такова. Делал по примеру распознавание лиц. И тут - бац! и выбивает ошибку. А конкретно в методе:

```
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor= 1.1,
    minNeighbors= 5,
    minSize=(10, 10)
)
```

Ошибка:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\monte\Desktop\Проекты\Python\MACHINE\try2.py", line 6, in 
> faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Полный код:

```
import cv2
image_path = "me.png"
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor= 1.1,
    minNeighbors= 5,
    minSize=(10, 10)
)
faces_detected = "Лиц обнаружено: " + format(len(faces))
print(faces_detected)
# Рисуем квадраты вокруг лиц
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
```

Я так подозреваю, судя по ошибке, что проблема где-то внутри библиотеки.

Как ее решить? Делал все по примеру, который везде. Что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml` в папку со скриптом.

Для проверки наличия файлов

```
import os

print(os.path.isfile('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Все так, подставил свое изображение(`lena.jpg`) и свою `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`.
Ищите другой `haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml`

```
import cv2
#image_path = "me.png"
image_path = "lena.jpg"                                                       # +

#face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    'opencv_videos/Face_Frame_Rate_plot/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'  # +
)

image = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor= 1.1,
    minNeighbors= 5,
    minSize=(10, 10)
)
faces_detected = "Лиц обнаружено: " + format(len(faces))
print(faces_detected)
# Рисуем квадраты вокруг лиц
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
    
cv2.imshow('Output', image)                                                   # +++
cv2.imwrite('lena_out.jpg', image)                                            # +++
cv2.waitKey(0)                                                                # +++
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]